# What is the first minimum OR saddle point (calculus derivative) of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, minimum, derivative

[image]

I have the following `numpy` array which is depicted above.

Functions like

```
print(arr.argsort()[:3])
```

will return the three lowest indeces of the three lowest value:

```
[69 66 70]
```

How do I return the **first** `index` where the first `minimum` or first `saddle point` (in the calculus sense) whichever comes first  of an array?

In this case the two numbers `0.62026396 0.60566623` at `index` 2 and 3 is a first `saddle point` (it isn't a true `saddle point` since the slope doesn't flatten, but it clearly breaks the hard downward slope there. Perhaps add a threshold of what "flattens" means). Since the function never goes up before the first `saddle point` and therefore the first `mimimum` occurs after the `saddle point`, that is the index I am interested in.

```
[1.04814804 0.90445908 0.62026396 0.60566623 0.32295758 0.26658469
 0.19059289 0.10281547 0.08582772 0.05091265 0.03391474 0.03844931
 0.03315003 0.02838656 0.03420759 0.03567401 0.038203   0.03530763
 0.04394316 0.03876966 0.04156067 0.03937291 0.03966426 0.04438747
 0.03690863 0.0363976  0.03171374 0.03644719 0.02989291 0.03166156
 0.0323875  0.03406287 0.03691943 0.02829374 0.0368121  0.02971704
 0.03427005 0.02873735 0.02843848 0.02101889 0.02114978 0.02128403
 0.0185619  0.01749904 0.01441699 0.02118773 0.02091855 0.02431763
 0.02472427 0.03186318 0.03205664 0.03135686 0.02838413 0.03206674
 0.02638371 0.02048122 0.01502128 0.0162665  0.01331485 0.01569286
 0.00901017 0.01343558 0.00908635 0.00990869 0.01041151 0.01063606
 0.00822482 0.01312368 0.0115005  0.00620334 0.0084177  0.01058152
 0.01198732 0.01451455 0.01605602 0.01823713 0.01685975 0.03161889
 0.0216687  0.03052391 0.02220871 0.02420951 0.01651778 0.02066987
 0.01999613 0.02532265 0.02589186 0.02748692 0.02191687 0.02612152
 0.02309497 0.02744753 0.02619196 0.02281516 0.0254296  0.02732746
 0.02567608 0.0199178  0.01831929 0.01776025]
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking for? Could you perhaps clarify this a bit? What is a minimum in the calculus sense? do you mean a local minimum, a minimum of the first derivative, or something else? Maybe it would be helpful to provide some valid Python copy-pastable input (and the expected outputs).

Comment: Local minima as in 
 https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/maxima-minima.html

Comment: As a general principle you would use `np.gradient()` to compute the derivatives and check where it changes sign (you will need first and second derivatives for both minima and saddle points), BUT keep in mind that this approach may not be numerically stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would detect local maxima/minima, inflection points, and saddles.

Let first define the following functions

```
import numpy as np


def n_derivative(arr, degree=1):
    """Compute the n-th derivative."""
    result = arr.copy()
    for i in range(degree):
        result = np.gradient(result)
    return result


def sign_change(arr):
    """Detect sign changes."""
    sign = np.sign(arr)
    result = ((np.roll(sign, 1) - sign) != 0).astype(bool)
    result[0] = False
    return result


def zeroes(arr, threshold=1e-8):
    """Find zeroes of an array."""
    return sign_change(arr) | (abs(arr) < threshold)
```

We can now make use of the [derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Higher-order_derivative_test)

A critical points will have first-derivative equal to zero.

```
def critical_points(arr):
    return zeroes(n_derivative(arr, 1))
```

If a critical point has the second-derivative non-zero, then the point is either a maximum or a minimum:

```
def maxima_minima(arr):
    return zeroes(n_derivative(arr, 1)) & ~zeroes(n_derivative(arr, 2))


def maxima(arr):
    return zeroes(n_derivative(arr, 1)) & (n_derivative(arr, 2) < 0)


def minima(arr):
    return zeroes(n_derivative(arr, 1)) & (n_derivative(arr, 2) > 0)
```

If the second-derivative is equal to zero but the third-derivative is non-zero, then the point is a point of inflection:

```
def inflections(arr):
    return zeroes(n_derivative(arr, 2)) & ~zeroes(n_derivative(arr, 3))
```

If a critical point has second-derivative equal to zero, but third-derivative is non-zero, then this is a saddle:

```
def inflections(arr):
    return zeroes(n_derivative(arr, 1)) & zeroes(n_derivative(arr, 2)) & ~zeroes(n_derivative(arr, 3))
```

Note that this method is numerically not stable, in the sense that, on one hand the zeroes are detected on some arbitrary threshold definition, and on the other hand different sampling may result in the function / array not being differentiable.
Hence, according to this definition, what you expect is actually not a saddle point.

To have a better approximation of a continuous function, one could use a cubic interpolation on a largely oversampled (as per `K` in the code) function, e.g.:

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.interpolate

data = [
    1.04814804, 0.90445908, 0.62026396, 0.60566623, 0.32295758, 0.26658469, 0.19059289,
    0.10281547, 0.08582772, 0.05091265, 0.03391474, 0.03844931, 0.03315003, 0.02838656,
    0.03420759, 0.03567401, 0.038203, 0.03530763, 0.04394316, 0.03876966, 0.04156067,
    0.03937291, 0.03966426, 0.04438747, 0.03690863, 0.0363976, 0.03171374, 0.03644719,
    0.02989291, 0.03166156, 0.0323875, 0.03406287, 0.03691943, 0.02829374, 0.0368121,
    0.02971704, 0.03427005, 0.02873735, 0.02843848, 0.02101889, 0.02114978, 0.02128403,
    0.0185619, 0.01749904, 0.01441699, 0.02118773, 0.02091855, 0.02431763, 0.02472427,
    0.03186318, 0.03205664, 0.03135686, 0.02838413, 0.03206674, 0.02638371, 0.02048122,
    0.01502128, 0.0162665, 0.01331485, 0.01569286, 0.00901017, 0.01343558, 0.00908635,
    0.00990869, 0.01041151, 0.01063606, 0.00822482, 0.01312368, 0.0115005, 0.00620334,
    0.0084177, 0.01058152, 0.01198732, 0.01451455, 0.01605602, 0.01823713, 0.01685975,
    0.03161889, 0.0216687, 0.03052391, 0.02220871, 0.02420951, 0.01651778, 0.02066987,
    0.01999613, 0.02532265, 0.02589186, 0.02748692, 0.02191687, 0.02612152, 0.02309497,
    0.02744753, 0.02619196, 0.02281516, 0.0254296, 0.02732746, 0.02567608, 0.0199178,
    0.01831929, 0.01776025]
samples = np.arange(len(data))
f = sp.interpolate.interp1d(samples, data, 'cubic')

K = 10
N = len(data) * K

x = np.linspace(min(samples), max(samples), N)
y = f(x)
```

Then, all these definitions can be visually tested with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot(samples, data, label='data')
plt.plot(x, y, label='f')
plt.plot(x, n_derivative(y, 1), label='d1f')
plt.plot(x, n_derivative(y, 2), label='d2f')
plt.plot(x, n_derivative(y, 3), label='d3f')
plt.legend()
for w in np.where(inflections(y))[0]:
    plt.axvline(x=x[w])
plt.show()
```

but even in this case, that point is not a saddle.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `np.gradient` or `np.diff` to evaluate differences (the first computes central differences, the second is just x[1:] - x[:-1]), then use `np.sign` to get the gradient sign and another `np.diff` to see where the sign changes. Then filter the positive sign changes (corresponding to minima):

```
 np.where(np.diff(np.sign(np.gradient(x))) > 0)[0][0]+2   #add 2 as each time you call np.gradient or np.diff you are substracting 1 in size, the first [0] is to get the positions, the second [0] is to get the "first" element
>> 8
x[np.where(np.diff(np.sign(np.gradient(x))) > 0)[0][0]+2]
>> 0.03420759
```

Comment: That isn't quite right (what I am looking for), but it may be that I am looking for the first saddle point OR first minima, whichever comes first.

Comment: `0.03420759` is the first local minimum of your data. I get exactly that with this method

Comment: Yes you are correct. I added that I may also be looking for the first saddle point as well. Upticked your answer because it is definitely correct.

Comment: @norok2  you are right, I thought I used np.diff twice. Therefore, the `+2` will give you the point "right after" the local minimum (and `+1` will give you the point "right before")

Answer (score 0):

After looking around a little bit and from the two suggestions given (so far), I did this:

```
import scipy
from scipy import interpolate

x = np.arange(0, 100)
spl = scipy.interpolate.splrep(x,arr,k=3) # no smoothing, 3rd order spline
ddy = scipy.interpolate.splev(x,spl,der=2) # use those knots to get second derivative 
print(ddy)

asign = np.sign(ddy)
signchange = ((np.roll(asign, 1) - asign) != 0).astype(int)
print(signchange)
```

This gives me the `second derivative`, which then I can analyse, for example, seeing where the sign changes happen:

```
[-0.894053   -0.14050616  0.61304067 -0.69407217  0.55458251 -0.16624336
 -0.0073225   0.12481963 -0.067218    0.03648846  0.02876712 -0.02236204
  0.00167794  0.01886512 -0.0136314   0.00953279 -0.01812436  0.03041855
 -0.03436446  0.02418512 -0.01458896  0.00429809  0.01227133 -0.02679232
  0.02168571 -0.0181437   0.02585209 -0.02876075  0.0214645  -0.00715966
  0.0009179   0.00918466 -0.03056938  0.04419937 -0.0433638   0.03557532
 -0.02904901  0.02010647 -0.0199739   0.0170648  -0.00298236 -0.00511529
  0.00630525 -0.01015011  0.02218007 -0.01945341  0.01339405 -0.01211326
  0.01710444 -0.01591092  0.00486652 -0.00891456  0.01715403 -0.01976949
  0.00573004 -0.00446743  0.01479495 -0.01448144  0.01794968 -0.02533936
  0.02904355 -0.02418628  0.01505374 -0.00499926  0.00302616 -0.00877499
  0.01625907 -0.01240068 -0.00578862  0.01351128 -0.00318733 -0.0010652
  0.0029     -0.0038062   0.0064102  -0.01799678  0.04422601 -0.0620881
  0.05587037 -0.04856099  0.03535114 -0.03094757  0.03028399 -0.01912546
  0.01726283 -0.01392421  0.00989012 -0.01948119  0.02504401 -0.02204667
  0.0197554  -0.01270022 -0.00260326  0.01038581 -0.00299247 -0.00271539
 -0.00744152  0.00784016  0.00103947 -0.00576122]

[0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]
```